# Confused about facebook like

Tags: facebook, like

We have a 'Website Page' on Facebook that people like and we post all our news on it etc.

We also have a 'like' button on our website which people click on.  When they click on it it seems to publish our page onto their wall which is great.

However, we would like it so when people press 'like' on our website, it 'likes' our Facebook website page.  Both counters are different, on our Facebook website page we have ~350 likes, on our website we have ~280 likes they seem to be individuals.

Any way we can make people 'like' our website page on FB?

Comment: The answer to my question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15299/how-to-tie-together-facebook-pages-and-main-website will probably help you.

Comment: @Peter thanks, so I **have** to use two separate links?

Comment: The solution I went for in the end was to have a Like button on most of the pages and a Like box instead on the front page. It's your call whether to do that or have the two side by side.

Comment: @Peter thanks, is there any special code for a like box, or is it simply just a link to the page itself?  I can't find much info on it.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/ - and don't forget to up-vote Nick's answer to the question, which is where I got that URL from.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47395/what-is-the-way-to-properly-implement-a-facebook-like-button-on-a-page-for-best -- You might find this question I answered yesterday useful as far as understanding when/where to use the different buttons from the Facebook Developer Plugins.

Answer (score 1):

In the Like Button code there is a place to enter the URL of the page to be liked. If left blank it defaults to the URL of the page the button is being displayed on. If you put the URL of your Facebook page into the Like Button code it should allow you to have a like button for your Facebook page on your website which would show the number of people that like your page on Facebook.

```
<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/YourPage" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>
```

That would be for the xfbml implementation, but you can get the code for the other versions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Just change the URL to the URL of your Facebook page.

I have this working on a website already.